# Excel averge up to certain date with a certain column requirement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to create an average rating over time chart in excel for each player in a game we are playing. In the table we use each player enters the date, their name, and their score on that specific day. I am wondering how to create a column in the table that calculates avg score up to that specific date and updates automatically for each data entry.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried AVERAGEIFS?

Comment: yes, but I am basically looking for a way to tell excel "if I am in Dave's row, calculate Daves average score up until this point"

Comment: Yep, `AVERAGEIFS` would work great for that (use Player as a criterion). How has your `AVERAGEIFS` attempt not worked?

Comment: even if the names change order over time? then what would the formula look like?

Comment: how would this be done for the last 10 entries

Answer (score 3):

As @BigBen stated AVERAGEIFS is the way to go:

```
=AVERAGEIFS([Score],[Date],"<="&[@Date],[Player],[@Player])
```

[image]

Comment: I get torn between trying to teach someone to fish, and just giving them a fish :-( Not faulting you for answering tho.

Comment: @BigBen I tend to agree, but since the OP was arguing with you that it would not work I wanted to prove your point.  I did this more as a backup to your argument.  You know, I tend to comment more than answer.

Comment: how would this be done for last x (10) number of entries

Comment: That is a different question